# How to stop NSTimer?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, timer, nstimer

I have a problem with invalidating different timers.

I have multiple timers (`NSTimer`) on a viewcontroller(settingsVC):

```
 class settingsVC: UIViewController {

// I use 12 timers
var timer1 = NSTimer()

// Seconds to end the timer. Set 12 timers
let timeInterval1:NSTimeInterval = 10

var timer2 = NSTimer()
let timeInterval2:NSTimeInterval = 20

var timer3 = NSTimer()
let timeInterval3:NSTimeInterval = 30

//and so on ... 12 timers
 }
```

With a `UIButton` (Start) a segue is performed. And for every different value of the variable 'picked', a different timer will be started in the same class:

```
    class settingsVC: UIViewcontroller {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let pickerDefaultsIntegerKey = "Picker" // nsuserdefaults key

        @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

      // segue to another viewcontroller        
      performSegueWithIdentifier("timerOn", sender: self)

      if picked == 1 {

      defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: pickerDefaultsIntegerKey)

            timer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval1,
            target: self,
            selector: "timerDidEnd:",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: false)

       print("timer1 started")            

    } else if picked == 2 {

     defaults.setInteger(2, forKey: pickerDefaultsIntegerKey)

            timer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval2,
            target: self,
            selector: "timerDidEnd:",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: false)

        print("timer2 started")          

    } else if   // ....and so on{........ }
    }
```

The method fired if timer ends, see selector:

```
         func timerDidEnd(timer:NSTimer){

    print("timer ended")

   // do other stuff

   }
```

I invalidate the timers with a button (Reset) for values from a variable ('pickerSavedSelection') which is updated by saved values in NSUserdefaults:

```
@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {

       if let pickerSavedSelection = defaults.integerForKey(pickerDefaultsIntegerKey) as Int?

    {

        if pickerSavedSelection == 1 {

            timer1.invalidate()

        } else if pickerSavedSelection == 2 {

            timer2.invalidate()

        } else if   //...and so on{....} 
       }
```

All goes well, if I outcomment the `perform segue` line and just let the user stay on this viewcontroller.The timers get invalidated correctly then: 
In the console I read 'timer1 started' and I do NOT read 'timer ended' when the resetButton is pressed.

But staying on this viewcontroller(settingsVC) is NOT the flow of my app.
When the `perform segue` line is executed and the user 'comes back' to the viewcontroller (settingsVC), the timers are not invalidated when user presses the resetButton: 
In the console I read 'timer1 started' and I DO read 'timer ended' when the resetButton is pressed.

How should I stop the timers, when users will 'exit' the viewcontroller and come back to reset the timers?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: I would print the address each timer that you start and each timer that you end, and I'd be willing to wager that you'll just find that there is a timer that was started but never invalidated. I bet it has nothing to do with that multithreading issue (as you're not showing us any multithreaded code), but rather just a simple logic error. I can imagine all sorts of paths here that would result in that behavior.

Comment: There is no multithreading code in this question, so the problem is not related to trying to stop the timer from the wrong thread.  Code isn't automatically multithreaded by magic.  As Rob is pointing out, the problem is likely that you're losing reference to the original timer that you've started (and as such, can never call `invalidate` on the actual timer that started).

Comment: codeDude, I recommend added any & all code from the "settingsVC" that is related to your timers, including where they are declared.

Comment: yea, I am not using any multithreading code as of yet. I have print each timer started and ended, and when I outcomment the segue it works like I want: In the console for example I read ' timer2 started' and when the resetbutton is pressed I do NOT read 'timer2 ended' (
    'func timerDidEnd(timer:NSTimer){
                print("timer ended")) }'. But when the segue is performed I read 'timer2 is started' and when the resetbutton is pressed I read 'timer2 ended'

Comment: @nhgrif Yes indeed, I am losing reference of the original timer. But how do I get the reference back? Ok, I will add some extra info on where and I how I declare my timers etc

Comment: @nhgrif I updated my question. I hope this provides enough information

Comment: Your code and your description are both jumbled and confused. Why don't you first state what you are trying to do, at a high level. Then talk about your current approach to achieve that goal and how it doesn't meet that need.

Comment: One thing I see that does not belong: When you define your timers, like `var timer1 = NSTimer()`, do not create an assign a timer. That allocates a timer object which never does anything, and is a very bad habit. Simply say `var timer1: NSTimer`. (Later, when you assign a timer to timer1 with  code like `timer1 = NSTimer.scheduleTimerscheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...` you create a new timer which overwrites the timer you created previously, and that other timer is simply lost. If you were using manual reference counting then that other timer would have been leaked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken at any given point in time, you are only triggering one `NSTimer`. All your different timers are differentiated only in time intervals. So, my suggestion would be to keep only one `NSTimer` and have your time interval differentiated. With different value picked you should first invalidate the timer and then restart it with new time interval. That said, your `reset` will then be much simplified and you do not need to save `pickerSavedSelection` in `NSUserDefaults`. This is how I would re-write this code:

```
class settingsVC: UIViewController {
    var timer = NSTimer()

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

        // segue to another viewcontroller
        performSegueWithIdentifier("timerOn", sender: self)

        if picked == 1 {
            self.timer.invalidate()

            self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerDidEnd:",
                userInfo: nil,
                repeats: false)

            print("timer1 started")
        } else if picked == 2 {
            self.timer.invalidate()

            self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20,
                target: self,
                selector: "timerDidEnd:",
                userInfo: nil,
                repeats: false)

            print("timer2 started")          

        } else if   // ....and so on{........ }
    }

    @IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

PS: As a side note, I would advise your `NSTimer` to start & stop from main thread. Use GCD for that.

Comment: I think this answer only actually answers the title of the question and doesn't actually address the problem.  The asker is only guessing (and seems to be incorrectly so) that the problem is related to threading.  At the end of the day, the problem is that he isn't able to stop a timer and the asker believes it's because they're not stopping it on the correct thread... but there's no multithreading in the question.

Comment: yea, I was only guessing indeed (I should not probably). Excuse my misleading title and guesses, I will update the question

Comment: @nhgrif I agree I was stumped by question title. I have corrected my post (didn't remove original stuff so it could benefit someone else may be). If you think this makes sense then request you to please remove that down vote!

Comment: @codeDude Could you please try with my updated post. Let me know if you have some specific reasons to keep different timers just for different time intervals. Would be more than happy to help figuring out the issue.

Comment: NO! There is no reason to start using multiple threads in a situation like this. Concurrent programming is tricky stuff to get correct, with lots of potential gotchas, and the potential for non-deterministic behavior and bugs that you can't find or reproduce. It's an especially bad idea for novices. It's like asking somebody who just started flight school to solo on an F16 fighter jet.

Comment: Don't use concurrency unless you know exactly what you are doing and why it is the right solution for the problem at hand. Further, Apple strongly discourages you from using NSThreads or pthreads, especially on iOS, since they they tie up critical system resources (physical memory). If you really need to use concurrency you should use GCD or NSOperationQueues, where the system manages the thread pool for you.

Comment: You **should** delete your original answer. It's seriously bad advice.

Comment: @DuncanC - I agree. But if you see I initially misunderstood the OP question due to off articulation. Please take a look at my Edited post for solution. I have not removed my earlier thoughts purposefully. Do you see some issue here?

Comment: I guess you are right @DuncanC. I've edited it. Do you think I should be down voted for this!

Comment: Not any more. I've switched my down-vote to an up-vote since your edited answer does offer constructive suggestions. As I said in my comment to the question, both the question and the code are a confused mess.

Comment: @Abhinav I did re-write my code with your suggestion. It makes my code better. It has given me a push in the right direction. But still the same exact problem occurs. I will try some iterating later today, and will update the information accordingly.

Comment: Sure @codeDude. Please keep posted on this. Would be happy to help!

Comment: thanks @Abhinav,DuncanC,nhgrif; It took me a while, but I re-arranged my whole project with your comments and answers in mind. Now I initiate the timer; var timer: NSTimer?.  And I have created a different 'flow' of the app, so I can now stop the timer on the same Viewcontroller with; self.timer?.invalidate(). So I no longer have a problem with the timer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your selector is not called when your timer is **invalidated**, it is called everytime your timer is **fired**. Since the timer is non-repeat, the selector get called only once. When your press reset button, timer is actually invalidated, you just didn't know because you misunderstood `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method.

Comment: It can be something like this. I will look into this. But if I am not mistaking it works likes this: At the end of timeInterval the selector calls the method (in this case timerDidEnd)? So timer.invalidated() should disable calling this method, right?